# How does this disassembly output correlate to the function source?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have the following function in C:

```
    uint    myFunction (uint    arrayLen,
             uint*  array
            )
{
  uint  i;
  uint  j;
  uint  sum = 0;

  for  (i = 0;  i < arrayLen/2;  i++)
    for  (j = 0;  j < arrayLen;  j++)
        if  (array[i*2] == array[j])
          sum += mySumFunction(arrayLen,array,6);

  mySortFunction(arrayLen,array);

  for  (i = 0;  i < arrayLen/2;  i++)
    for  (j = 0;  j < arrayLen;  j++)
        if  (array[i*2] == array[j])
          sum -= mySumFunction(arrayLen,array,7);

  return(sum);
}
```

And here's the output for the disassemble command on the function

```
 Dump of assembler code for function myFunction:
0x080486a8 <myFunction+0>:  push   %ebp
0x080486a9 <myFunction+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080486ab <myFunction+3>:  sub    $0x1c,%esp
0x080486ae <myFunction+6>:  call   0x8048418 <mcount@plt>
0x080486b3 <myFunction+11>: movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
0x080486ba <myFunction+18>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
0x080486c1 <myFunction+25>: jmp    0x8048713 <myFunction+107>
0x080486c3 <myFunction+27>: movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080486ca <myFunction+34>: jmp    0x8048707 <myFunction+95>
0x080486cc <myFunction+36>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486cf <myFunction+39>: shl    $0x3,%eax
0x080486d2 <myFunction+42>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486d5 <myFunction+45>: mov    (%eax),%edx
0x080486d7 <myFunction+47>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080486da <myFunction+50>: shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080486dd <myFunction+53>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486e0 <myFunction+56>: mov    (%eax),%eax
0x080486e2 <myFunction+58>: cmp    %eax,%edx
0x080486e4 <myFunction+60>: jne    0x8048703 <myFunction+91>
0x080486e6 <myFunction+62>: movl   $0x6,0x8(%esp)
0x080486ee <myFunction+70>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486f1 <myFunction+73>: mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x080486f5 <myFunction+77>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080486f8 <myFunction+80>: mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x080486fb <myFunction+83>: call   0x8048668 <mySumFunction>
0x08048700 <myFunction+88>: add    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x08048703 <myFunction+91>: addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
0x08048707 <myFunction+95>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804870a <myFunction+98>: cmp    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804870d <myFunction+101>:    jb     0x80486cc <myFunction+36>
0x0804870f <myFunction+103>:    addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048713 <myFunction+107>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048716 <myFunction+110>:    shr    %eax
0x08048718 <myFunction+112>:    cmp    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0804871b <myFunction+115>:    ja     0x80486c3 <myFunction+27>
0x0804871d <myFunction+117>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048720 <myFunction+120>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048724 <myFunction+124>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048727 <myFunction+127>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x0804872a <myFunction+130>:    call   0x80485cc <mySortFunction>
0x0804872f <myFunction+135>:    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048736 <myFunction+142>:    jmp    0x8048788 <myFunction+224>
0x08048738 <myFunction+144>:    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
0x0804873f <myFunction+151>:    jmp    0x804877c <myFunction+212>
0x08048741 <myFunction+153>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048744 <myFunction+156>:    shl    $0x3,%eax
0x08048747 <myFunction+159>:    add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0804874a <myFunction+162>:    mov    (%eax),%edx
0x0804874c <myFunction+164>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804874f <myFunction+167>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
0x08048752 <myFunction+170>:    add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048755 <myFunction+173>:    mov    (%eax),%eax
0x08048757 <myFunction+175>:    cmp    %eax,%edx
0x08048759 <myFunction+177>:    jne    0x8048778 <myFunction+208>
0x0804875b <myFunction+179>:    movl   $0x7,0x8(%esp)
0x08048763 <myFunction+187>:    mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048766 <myFunction+190>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x0804876a <myFunction+194>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804876d <myFunction+197>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048770 <myFunction+200>:    call   0x8048668 <mySumFunction>
0x08048775 <myFunction+205>:    sub    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
0x08048778 <myFunction+208>:    addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
0x0804877c <myFunction+212>:    mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804877f <myFunction+215>:    cmp    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048782 <myFunction+218>:    jb     0x8048741 <myFunction+153>
0x08048784 <myFunction+220>:    addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048788 <myFunction+224>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804878b <myFunction+227>:    shr    %eax
0x0804878d <myFunction+229>:    cmp    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048790 <myFunction+232>:    ja     0x8048738 <myFunction+144>
0x08048792 <myFunction+234>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x08048795 <myFunction+237>:    leave  
0x08048796 <myFunction+238>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I was wondering if someone could help me read and translate the assembly instructions to the C code above. I was specifically looking for an explanation regarding the division portion seen in the code `(arrayLen/2)`. I was under the impression that it would translate into a right shift instruction, but when I didn't see that in the assembly code I wasn't sure what was happening.

**Edit:** I've added the missing assembly code. It also looks like I found the explanation for the division portion.

Comment: Is this Intel?  Have you tried looking at what the assembly opcodes mean e.g. on Wikipedia (after they lift the SOPA blackout :-)?  If you look at the meaning of the opcodes, it's fairly straightforward to translate.  If you get stuck on something specific and ask about that, you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: yea wiki was down. i'll check it out when it's back up. thanks though.

Comment: I don't see how this question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical. It fits perfectly into the "I want someone to explain X to me" criteria in the FAQ. Voting to re-open as the accepted answer deserves more attention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have the whole function, but here's a breakdown of what's here:

These 3 instructions set up your stack frame:

```
0x080486a8 <myFunction+0>:  push   %ebp
0x080486a9 <myFunction+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080486ab <myFunction+3>:  sub    $0x1c,%esp
```

I'm not sure what this is for:

```
0x080486ae <myFunction+6>:  call   0x8048418 <mcount@plt>
```

This is i and sum getting initialized to 0 (the are stored on the stack):

```
0x080486b3 <myFunction+11>: movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
0x080486ba <myFunction+18>: movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
```

This is the beginning of the outer for loop.  Typically, a loop in assembly starts by jumping to the end.  The end in this case is past the end of your assembly listing.

```
0x080486c1 <myFunction+25>: jmp    0x8048713 <myFunction+107>
```

This is j getting initialized to 0.  It's done here because it has to be reset every time the outer for loop runs.

```
0x080486c3 <myFunction+27>: movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
```

This is the beginning of the inner for loop.

```
0x080486ca <myFunction+34>: jmp    0x8048707 <myFunction+95>
```

This indexes array by i*2 by doing pointer arithmetic on the address of array.  First it puts i into eax, then left shifts it 3 (multiplying it by 8).  This is an optimization of the *2 as well as accounting for the size of elements of array (4).  Finally it adds this to the address of array, storing the result in eax.

```
0x080486cc <myFunction+36>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486cf <myFunction+39>: shl    $0x3,%eax
0x080486d2 <myFunction+42>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
```

This takes the value pointed to by address calculated above and stores it in edx. In this dialect of assembly x(y) means *(y+x)

```
0x080486d5 <myFunction+45>: mov    (%eax),%edx
```

This calculates array[j] in a similar fashion, storing the result in eax this time:

```
0x080486d7 <myFunction+47>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080486da <myFunction+50>: shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080486dd <myFunction+53>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486e0 <myFunction+56>: mov    (%eax),%eax
```

This checks the two calculations above to see if they are equal:

```
0x080486e2 <myFunction+58>: cmp    %eax,%edx
```

If the check doesn't pass (if they are not equal), skip the inside of the if.  (This jumps past the end of your listing) jne means "jump if not equal"

```
0x080486e4 <myFunction+60>: jne    0x8048703 <myFunction+91>
```

These instructions load the arguments of mySumFunction into the proper places:

```
0x080486e6 <myFunction+62>: movl   $0x6,0x8(%esp)
0x080486ee <myFunction+70>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486f1 <myFunction+73>: mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
```

If the listing is cut off here, but hopefully this gives you a good general idea.

Comment: you're a life saver. i can't believe i was missing part of the code. thanks!

Comment: @splat:  this matches my analysis too.  I think `mcount@plt` is a c runtime library profiling function.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the beginning.

the first lines are declare vars, and the condition of the loop.

This part

```
0x080486cc <myFunction+36>: mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486cf <myFunction+39>: shl    $0x3,%eax
0x080486d2 <myFunction+42>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486d5 <myFunction+45>: mov    (%eax),%edx
0x080486d7 <myFunction+47>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080486da <myFunction+50>: shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080486dd <myFunction+53>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080486e0 <myFunction+56>: mov    (%eax),%eax
0x080486e2 <myFunction+58>: cmp    %eax,%edx
0x080486e4 <myFunction+60>: jne    0x8048703 <myFunction+91>
```

is like `if (%ebp[0xc[2*%ebp[-0xc]]]!=%ebp[0xc[%ebp[8]]]) goto myFunction+91;`
I guess that it's the `if  (array[i*2] == array[j])`

Comment: thanks asaelr! this helped a bit